# Get data attribute into event tracking

Tags: google-analytics, custom-data-attribute, event-tracking

I have a button

```
<button data-z="myvalue">
click
</button>
```

which clicks i want to track in Google Analytics (Universal - analytics.js).

I try it with

```
<button data-z="myvalue" 
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'clickout', 'buttonclick', window.location.href, getAttribute('data-z'));>
click
</button>
```

With `window.location.href` i get the current URL (work), and with `getAttribute('data-z')` i want to get the myvalue from `data-z` (doesn't work).

Any help is appreciated!

PS: JQuery based solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not telling your getAttribute method to which element the attribute belongs - getAttribute does not exists on its own, it is a method of a DOM object (your button in this case).

Since you are using inline Javascript the DOM object will be available by using the "this" keyword in the click function to call the getAttribute of the button:

```
<button data-z="myvalue" 
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'clickout', 'buttonclick', window.location.href, this.getAttribute('data-z'));>
click
</button>
```

Much less expensive than jQuery selectors (however using jQuery you could dispense with inline scripts and attach the click in an javascript function. Mixing HTML and JS is not elegant).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution, using jQuery, would be to evaluate for the the clicked element first to acquire the attribute value, and then pass that into the onclick handler:

```
onclick="var d=$(this).data('z'); ga('send', 'event', 'clickout', 'buttonclick', window.location.href, d);"
```